# How to count number of fields inside an embedded documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document as given below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58f5f4e0e405972824b8ff03"),
    "type" : "Defect Status",
    "data" : {
        "1" : [ "121764", "Bug", "7/6/15", "Closed" ],
        "2" : [ "121830", "Bug", "7/7/15", "Closed" ],
        "3" : [ "122333", "Bug", "7/16/15","Closed"],
        "4" : [ "122339", "Bug", "7/16/15","Closed"],
        "5" : [ "122340", "Bug", "7/16/15", "Closed"]
     }
}
```

I want to calculate the number of fields inside the `data` field which is an embedded document inside another document. As it is not an array so, I can't find a way.

Comment: A good reason why `data` probably _should_ be an array. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the new `$objectToArray` expression introduced in version 3.4.4: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18794

```
db.test.aggregate([{$project: {data_size: {$size: {$objectToArray: "$data"}}}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the host language. Once you do a `db.find()` to fetch the document (call it `d`), invoke

```
Object.keys(d).length
```

assuming your host language is JavaScript. There are similar ways to do this for Python, Ruby, or Java hosts, or any other host language.